# Why do DHCP clients leave the port open after the lease now?

Tags: networking, dhcp, network-protocols

I've noticed on some embedded linux systems that both dhcpcd and systemd-networkd leave the DHCP client port 68 open after the lease has been acquired. The fact both systems do this indicates it's a best practice if not a standard.

The base DHCP standard does not require this: the handshake of DISCOVER-OFFER-REQUEST-ACK runs it's course and there's no need to communicate with the server again until T1 of the lease is reached and the client renews.

Why are these clients leaving this port open now?

Comment: how are you assessing the state of the port? netstat?

Comment: Could it be as simple as IPTABLES rules with "established/related" rules matching this?

Comment: Yep, "netstat -plunt" udp port 68 is open.  It's not tcp so it doesn't get counted as "listening" state since it has no state.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really directly linked to the DHCP protocol, but rather to how the ports structure in general works:

> If a port is open on your computer, it means that there is an active program using this port number to communicate with other computers on
> the web. A port isn’t opened by the operating system, it’s opened by a
> specific program wanting to use it.
>
> To close a port, it’s usually only necessary to shut down the program
> holding the port open. On some ports it’s enough to tell the program
> or service that the port should not be opened.

[Source: Emisoft Blog](https://blog.emsisoft.com/en/4389/how-to-close-port/)

Also:

> The [..] use of the terms "open" and "closed" can sometimes be
> misleading, though; it blurs the distinction between a given port
> being reachable (unfiltered) and whether there is an application
> actually listening on that port. Technically, a given port being
> "open" (in this context, reachable) is not enough for a communication
> channel to be established. There needs to be an application (service)
> listening on that port, accepting the incoming packets and processing
> them. If there is no application listening on a port, incoming packets
> to that port will simply be rejected by the computer's operating
> system.

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port)

This means that seeing a port as "open" actually equals to knowing that there is a service running which is in need of that port in order to function normally. It does not mean it is currently actively using that port to send messages.

So, basically, it is normal that port 68 will be "open" as long as your system sees itself as a DHCP Client, i.e. as long as networking is active.

It is not really the task of a specific program or protocol to "open" or "close" a port, or to control the traffic going through it. When we speak of an "open" port, we just mean there's a program/service active which could receive incoming messages on that port, and which therefore could be susceptible to maliciously crafted messages by an attacker.

That's where Firewalls come in: they filter or block the traffic before other programs/services actually can receive it. Usuallly, a firewall will block any traffic to port 68 which is not DHCP traffic. You probably could additionally configure the firewall to only accept DHCP traffic from your specific DHCP server(s) or relay(s), effectively blocking any "outside" traffic.

From [the same Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_port):

> Ports can be "closed" (in this context, filtered) through the use of a
> firewall. The firewall will filter incoming packets, only letting
> through those packets for which it has been configured. Packets
> directed at a port which the firewall is configured to "close" will
> simply be dropped in transit, as though they never existed.

---

### EDIT **for clarification**:

"Port x is open" is equivalent to "there's a service running which uses port x as communication channel".

"Closing" a port is equivalent of terminating (or [killing](https://askubuntu.com/a/410225)) the associated service. Furthermore, at OS level, any port can be associated to maximum one service at any given time (the port number effectively indicates to the OS to which service it needs to forward a given packet). Keeping port 68 open means keeping it "reserved" for DHCP. An OS could theoretically "split" DHCP into a "timing" service and a "caller" service. But since DHCP is critical for guaranteeing network connectivity (unless the IP is static), you could see it as "best practice" to just keep the service running and thus leave the port open.  A closed port theoretically can be requested and used by any application, so a rogue application could reserve port 68, effectively hindering the system from renewing the IP lease from the DHCP server and thus effectively interrupting any network connection.

Keep in mind that an open port in itself is not in any way dangerous: [further reading](https://securitytrails.com/blog/open-ports)

Comment: But couldn't a client just release the port when not in use?  Logically a firewall doesn't know anything about the state of the daemons on a system and is in a terrible place to make time-based decisions on whether to accept traffic on a port.
Notably we have logs of version 3 of dhcpcd doing this

Comment: @davolfman See my edit

Comment: This may be a reasonable explanation:  I had considered it.  Especially with systemd now providing a DHCP client you may not know you have, it could make sense for a client to keep the port to try to prevent another client accidentally invoked or installed from stealing it.

My other theory is it's to keep noncompliant servers from trying to reclaim the IP of your host as a wireless device that's left the network.

I just wish there was some documentation somewhere.   Also if ports are open every CVE that could be involved needs to be evaluated more. Which is a pain on a custom system.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this much later.  There's a very good reason for a DHCP client to hold ports open if it's not running as root: it might not be able to reopen them.

If a DHCP client has for example been run as a user and had it's ports assigned by systemd, then it won't be able to reacquire them if it lets them go.  The file descriptors would just be closed and only root can reopen them on specific ports.

So if you were designing a DHCP client to run in a modern way on a modern system you might never bother to write code that dynamically discarded and reacquired your response ports because it only adds a little to your security posture on a system where you've got a network daemon running as root.

Comment: This would indeed be the main reason for keeping a port open _forever_. Many services, such as Apache2, first open ports (80, 443 for Apache2) then drops privileges from root to its own user (httpd or www-data, depending on your OS).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in
[RFC 2131 - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2131.html)
section 4.1, and especially this paragraph:

> DHCP clients are responsible for all message retransmission.  The
> client MUST adopt a retransmission strategy that incorporates a
> randomized exponential backoff algorithm to determine the delay
> between retransmissions.  The delay between retransmissions SHOULD be
> chosen to allow sufficient time for replies from the server to be
> delivered based on the characteristics of the internetwork between
> the client and the server.  For example, in a 10Mb/sec Ethernet
> internetwork, the delay before the first retransmission SHOULD be 4
> seconds randomized by the value of a uniform random number chosen
> from the range -1 to +1.  Clients with clocks that provide resolution
> granularity of less than one second may choose a non-integer
> randomization value.  The delay before the next retransmission SHOULD
> be 8 seconds randomized by the value of a uniform number chosen from
> the range -1 to +1.  The retransmission delay SHOULD be doubled with
> subsequent retransmissions up to a maximum of 64 seconds.  The client
> MAY provide an indication of retransmission attempts to the user as
> an indication of the progress of the configuration process.

In other words, the client is charged with  Message Retransmission:

Since DHCP uses the unreliable
[User Datagram Protocol (UDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)
for messaging, clients are responsible for detecting message loss and
retransmitting requests if need be.

Comment: But the port remains held by the client software long after the ACK has been received and the IP address accepted and it no longer has reason to communicate in either direction.  By this point the program is asleep long-term and not sending anything until the time comes to renew.

Comment: I can't guarantee that the program is behaving correctly. All I'm saying is that it's supposed to keep on listening on the port and doing retransmission if required. While waiting on the port for a message that doesn't arrive it will be in kernel wait, so indeed not active.

Comment: As I read the standard if the client has not received an ack it should not assign the address and should instead reattempt leasing after it times out.  I'm not even sure this behavior is technically DHCP, just implemented by two unrelated clients.

Comment: The standard is vague, leaving some space for client implementation. Retransmission is the explanation that I found in it. It can simply be a badly implemented retransmission client. DHCP clients are most likely using common blocks of code from ulterior versions so may have similar behavior, including unintended one.